# Fanpage: embedding an external app from a non SSL-secured source

Tags: external, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, facebook-page

newbie here!.

I'm creating an app for a fan page to embed a Flash 'miniwebsite' in the FB page. I've been reading that it's now compulsory to have an https connection in order to show external content. Unfortunately the hosting of the external miniwebsite does not (and will not) have an SSL certificate.

Given that this app will only 'show' this external website (that is, no info/data from the visitor will be asked/required, as it's an informational site rather than a transactional site), **is there any (allowed) way to use this app in the fan page without a SSL-secured source?**

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, an acceptable solution for me would be if I could simply publish an image (like a 'poster') to be permanently displayed in 'a' main tab of the fan page so those users interested in visiting the website could just click on the image and be forwarded to the site. **Can this be done?, and if so, how?**.

Thanks a lot for your assistance.

PS: Please in your responses note that I'm a newbie in programming so be gentle! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put up your own website that has both http/https for the authentication parts and satisfy the app settings requirement, and then from your code once authenticated, just serve the video content from the "video server".  So in effect you have a "wrapper" website around the video content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a free app to solve your problem, just search it.